# Datepicker icon not aligned properly with textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two textbox with datepicker, currently I am using a button icon for selecting the date. My problem is the button is appearing directly below the textbox whereas I would like it to align directly to the right side of the textbox. I believe I would need to work on CSS to achieve the results.

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn:"button",
        buttonText: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>"
       
    });
    
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn:"button",
        buttonText: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>"
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="form-group row">
   <div style="float:left;" class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>Date 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1"/>
              
    </div>
    <div style="float:left" class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>Date 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2"/>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply this css using `position:absolute;`

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn:"button",
        buttonText: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>"
       
    });
    
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn:"button",
        buttonText: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>"
       
    });
```

```css
.form-group{
   position:relative;}
   
.ui-datepicker-trigger{
    right: 16px;
    top: 26px;
    position: absolute;}
    
.ui-datepicker-trigger span{
    line-height:26px;}
    
.form-control{
    padding-right:30px!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="form-group row">
   <div style="float:left;" class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>Date 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1"/>
              
    </div>
    <div style="float:left" class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>Date 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2"/>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Lifesaver. I guess I have a lot of css to learn. Thanks a lot. Solves my problem so marking it as answer.

Comment: @subhrendu Welcome Mate